# Python help "***keyword can't be an expression" error

Tags: python, numpy

I am using python 2.7.8 64-bit. I am trying to import a CSV file with the numpy package. I keep getting the ***keyword can't be an expression, then it gives me the path and says line 6, so I'm assuming line 6 is where the problem is.

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np

def main():

    try:
        date, rate, arb = np.loadtext('TutSheet.csv'.
                                    delimter=',',
                                    unpack=True,
                                    dtype='str')

        print date

    except Exception, e:
            print str(e)
```

Comment: Post the actual error message with stacktrace

Comment: I would suggest adding a linter like pyflakes, or flake8 to your editor.  it would catch simple syntax errors like this.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This is the actual code that would produce the error described.

Comment: @Tritium21, yes I gathered that, I just presumed you had typos from manually typing in your code originally

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have a few typos:

```
import  numpy as np
try:
    date, rate, arb = np.loadtxt('TutSheet.csv', #<- comma not a period
                                delimiter=',', # <- delimiter not delimter
                                unpack=True,
                                dtype='str')
    print date

except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. When I make the above corrections, my next issue is that my print is still in orange for both cases in the above code. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by orange? As is the code runs fine, just make sure you don't include the `<-` lines

Comment: Right, I leave out the <-, but for example, if I were to post my code, the print would not be in blue, like it is in yours. It would be orange for print, like it is for the words "import, try, and def"

Comment: **delimiter** not  `delimter`

Comment: If you have Skype I can show you quickly, will.bunker3

Comment: I don't have skype on this, copy paste the code above and run it

Comment: What you see is called [*syntax highlighting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting#Examples).

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have a dot instead of a comma, leaving off the other three:

```
np.loadtext('TutSheet.csv'.delimter=',')
```

`'Tutsheet.csv'.delimter` isn't an allowed keyword argument. You meant `'Tutsheet.csv', delimter=','`.

Comment: it is delimiter not delimter

Answer (score 2):

you just have a typo : you need a `,` after `'TutSheet.csv'` , not a `.`